# How to get outline mode when read bash shell using vim

Tags: linux, vim

I am reading a long bash shell script using vim, and I want to read all function in outline mode, what can I do in vim?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Vim doesn't have this feature out of the box, you need to install a plugin called [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) or a more recent alternative called [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you wish to *fold* all functions to make the code easier to browse.

```
:set foldmethod=syntax
:set foldlevel=1
```

For more information see:

- [`:help folding`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#folding)